# How to do this without using trigonometric substitution?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac {\rho^2}{(\rho^2+ h^2)^\frac 32} d\rho$$

Comment: Isn't this just a standard trigonometric substitution?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question.

Comment: You should first get rid of $h$ by introducing $\rho=hu \implies d\rho = hdu$.

Comment: I think your question would get more traction if you were asking something like "How to do trig substitution problems without using trig substitution" rather than "Solve my problem please, and without using the most obvious method." Or even something along the lines of asking how to do trigonometric substitution, if whats' really going on here is simply that you don't understand the method.

Comment: @MrYouMath But that doesn't change anything.

Comment: (also, it would probably help if you included a motivation for why you are looking for a solution method that isn't the usual one)

Comment: @Hurkyl Okay, done.

Comment: @Hurkyl Because...curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Prove that

$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\ dx=\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})+c$$

Let $x=tu$ to see that

$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{t^2u^2+1}}\ du=\frac1t\ln(tu+\sqrt{1+t^2u^2})+c$$

Then differentiate with respect to $t$ to see that

$$\int\frac{u^2}{(t^2u^2+1)^{3/2}}\ du=-\frac1t\frac d{dt}\left(\frac1t\ln(tu+\sqrt{1+t^2u^2})+c\right)$$

Be careful, and notice that differentiating $c$ with respect to $t$ is still a constant of integration *with respect to $u$*.

Now multiply both sides by $t^3$ to finally get

$$\int\frac{u^2}{(u^2+\frac1{t^2})^{3/2}}\ du=-t^2\frac d{dt}\left(\frac1t\ln(tu+\sqrt{1+t^2u^2})\right)+c$$

and then let $t\mapsto\frac1t$ to get your final answer.

Comment: Hm, I believe we should also assume $t>0$.

Comment: One may perhaps notice through recognition that$$\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\ dx=\operatorname{arcsinh}(x)+c$$

Comment: The first formula is basic.

Comment: Got it. But how to prove $$\int\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\ dx=\ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})+c$$ without using trigonometric substitution?

Comment: @BeckHumh Well, as my second comment mentions, you may just recognize the integral, or let $x=e^u-e^{-u}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{\quad\rho = {h^{2} - t^{2} \over 2t}\,,\quad
> t = \root{\rho^{2} + h^{2}} - \rho}$

\begin{align}
&\int{\rho^{2} \over \pars{\rho^{2} + h^{2}}^{3/2}}\,\dd\rho =
\int\bracks{-\,{1 \over t} + {4h^{2}t \over \pars{t^{2} + h^{2}}^{2}}}\,\dd t =
-\ln\pars{t} - {2h^{2} \over t^{2} + h^{2}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\ln\pars{\root{\rho^{2} + h^{2}} - \rho} -
{2h^{2} \over \pars{\root{\rho^{2} + h^{2}} - \rho}^{2} + h^{2}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

I have taken this clue from another answer posted on another question.

First substitute $\rho=\frac1t$, I get:
$$-\int\frac{dt}{t(1+h^2t^2)^{3/2}}$$
Then change $t^2\rightarrow t$, I get:$$\frac{-1}{2}\int\frac{dt}{t(1+th^2)^{3/2}}$$
After this substitute $t=\frac{u^2-1}{h^2}$, which makes the integral:$$-\int\frac{du}{u^2(u^2-1)}$$
After this, apply partial fraction and integrating gives the solution.

Comment: :-) don't forget to factor a bit more at the end.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the pythagorean identities for circular trig functions, such as

$$ 1 + \tan^2 x = \sec^2 x $$

and for the hyperbolic trig functions, such as

$$ 1 + \sinh^2 x = \cosh^2 x $$

there is a similar identity involving rational functions:

$$ 1 + \left( \frac{y^2 - 1}{2y} \right)^2 = \left( \frac{y^2 + 1}{2y} \right)^2 $$

The various forms of this identity can be computed as needed from

$$ (2y)^2 + (y^2 - 1)^2 = (y^2 + 1)^2 $$

So, for example, when one has

$$ \sqrt{1 + x^2} \, \mathrm{d} x$$

one could make the substitution

$$x = \frac{y^2 - 1}{2y} \qquad \qquad y > 0$$

to get

$$ \left( \frac{y^2 + 1}{2y} \right) \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{y^2} \right) \mathrm{d} y \right) $$

With the square root eliminated, the problem can then be solved via partial fractions. Although in this example the denominator is a power of $y$, so you have the much simpler method of just expanding everything.

Similarly, one could substitute $x = \frac{2y}{y^2 - 1}$ instead.